# Arrays and Classes unityscript

Tags: arrays, class, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Here is a class Card and a 2d array aGrid.

The 2d array aGrid is set to aGrid = new Card[4,4]; it looks like I am making it an instance of the Card class and an array at the same time. How does this work??

I thought a variable could only be set to one type of thing ---> an object instance or an array but not both.

Here is the code:

```
class Card extends System.Object {
    var isFace:boolean = false;
    var isMatched:boolean = false;
}

var aGrid:Card[,];//2d array to keep track of the shuffled, dealt cards

var aGrid = new Card[4,4];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning to aGrid an **array** of Cards, not a single card.

You should probably call:

```
aGrid = new Card[4,4];
```

If you were to call:

```
aGrid = new Card();
```

then it would assing a Card instance to aGrid.

Comment: so new Card only means that all the array can accept is cards??